# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm getting a typescript error with version 2.0.3 on line 6.

```
 private getFormEncode(formValues: any): string {
    let str: Array<any> = [];
    for (let key of Object.keys(formValues)) {
      const name: string = encodeURIComponent(key);
      const value: string =  encodeURIComponent(formValues[key]);
      str.push(`${name}=${value}`);
    }
    return str.join('&');
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the code that results in the error? Which exactly is line 6? As you obviously have more code before this snippet (it's a class method after all)

Comment: Adding the correct type to the str variable fix the typescript complain.
thanks @NitzanTomer

Comment: @jgatjens - can you show what you added as I have the same issue and have my types on all my variables.

Comment: @fidev I added the Array<any>  to the str variable that would let you put any type of data on the Array.

Comment: @jgatjens, you might want to post the answer you found for the problem, it also worked for me, thanks

Comment: @Gedeon you can click on the edited date and see what was the problem.

Comment: Setting it as `Array<any>` is just circumventing the transpiler warning. Any error might still exist. The type there should be `string[]`.